# Is it normal for condensation to drip without the HVAC unit running?

Tags: hvac

I am noticing that my condensation drip pipe on the house is dripping even when the AC/Heating unit is not running.  Is this normal?

Comment: If this line is your primary condensate drain line, then it is normal for it to drip when the evaporator/air-handler has cycled off. But I think that in some installations the *visible* condensate line outside the house is a secondary (overflow) line which only flows if the primary condensate drain is plugged, and *any* overflow is an indication of a plugged primary path. Is your evaporator-air handler in the attic or on the ground floor? In our house the air handler is on the ground floor and the condensate drains into a sewer pipe through a trap into the sewer under the slab.

Comment: You can clear the path through the visible line by suctioning on the visible overflow line. Dump the contents of the shop vac before you start so you can see how much water you vacuum out.

Comment: my car AC drips for an hour or two when it's muggy, a home isn't much different...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is normal for condensate to drip for a while after the unit runs. If you have a steady drip for hours it is possible the drain is partily plugged and the tray is filling up cleaning the drain line is required to fix this. If there is a steady flow for a long period it may be the evaporator is icing up from dirty filters or low air flow across the coils. The last possibility is a incorrect Freon level usually a low level will cause ice on the evaporator but an overcharge can also cause this but this is less common now with licensing required to service Freon based systems.